# Who is self referring to?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to understand the use of the keyword `self` Let's say that I have two classes one called 
AppDelegate and one called Photo. Photo is my "model" class in the MVC paradigm and AppDelegate is the controller.In the `init` method of the Photo class below. Who is self referring to?

```
-(id) init
{
    if( self = [super init] ){
        [self setCaption:@"Default Caption"];
        [self setPhotographer:@"Default Photographer"];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is the object that received the message. In instance methods, it's the instance that received the message; in class methods, it's the class that received the message.

So, in `init`, `self` is the instance you're initializing—the instance that something sent an `init` message to, probably (hopefully) immediately after receiving it from `alloc`.

If you make a convenience constructor, such as this:

```
//Returns a new, autoreleased Foobar instance.
+ (id) foobar
```

that's a class method, so in this method, `self` will refer to the `Foobar` class:

```
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

The implementation:

1. Sends an `alloc` message to `self` (the class); assuming you didn't override `alloc` (and you normally wouldn't), it will hit NSObject's implementation, which will respond by creating and returning an uninitialized instance.
2. Sends an `init` message to that instance; that message hits your `init` instance method, which calls up to super, does whatever initialization is necessary, and returns `self` (which, in `init`, is the instance).
3. Sends an `autorelease` message to that instance; again, you normally wouldn't override this, so it hits NSObject's implementation, which adds the instance to the nearest autorelease pool and returns it.
4. Finally, returns the freshly allocated, initialized, and autoreleased instance.

Comment: I finally understand this concept. Thank you very much Mr. Hosey :D

Answer (score 1):

`self` is the object you're sending a message to. For instance, if you call something like `[foo doSomething]`, in the `doSomething` method, `self` will be equal to `foo`. It's a hidden argument passed to methods.

It might be confusing that `self` is not read-only in Objective-C. For instance, in the initializer, as you may see, you actually override `self`:

```
if( self = [super init] ){
```

This is because `[super init]` is actually entitled to return a completely different object. However, you're just changing the value of a variable passed as an argument; you're not changing the value in the scope that called the method.

```
Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
// ... may be different of...
Foo* foo = [Foo alloc];
Foo* bar = [foo init];
```

In this example, in the second case, `foo` and `bar` may actually point to two distinct objects. Both `alloc` and `init` return a pointer to an object, and technically they *could* be different (though the only one you'll want to keep is the one `init` returned, since the object pointed to by `alloc`'s return value isn't ready for use).

As mentioned above, `self` is actually one of two hidden arguments methods receive. The other hidden argument is named `_cmd` and contains the selector used to call the method. You rarely need it.

This means that whenever you see this:

```
id bar = [foo doSomethingWithInt:5];
```

You could (symbolically) resolve it to a function call similar to this:

```
id bar = Foo_doSomething(foo, @selector(doSomethingWithInt:), 5);
```

So `self` is really just an argument.

Comment: If you replace “`Foo_doSomething`” with `objc_msgSend`, that's exactly what the compiler does. ☺

Comment: @Peter Hosey There's more magic involved, though. `objc_sendMsg` has to lookup the selector for the object's class.

Comment: zneak: Huh? There is no selector for a class, and the selector for the method is passed in by the compiler (it's the second argument, just as it is to the method implementation).

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant: If you assign the method implementation to `Foo_doSomething`, then you can use code such as that to call it directly. Right on.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, `**self**` is referring to the instance of the object where you have defined init.  It is analogous to '**`this`**' in C++.